# Internet connection breaks when connecting to video projector

Tags: internet, hdmi, projector

I have a problem with internet connection. When I connect my video pojector to the laptop via HDMI and switch for mirror display or other external display views, I lose the internet connection. I have no issues with another external monitor I daily use and I had no issues with the projector too until today. I have ubuntu 18.04
This is the dmesg output error:

```
[ 3743.227542] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Queue 10 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [46, 94] HW [46, 94] FH TRB=0x0c010a03d
    [ 3743.227701] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
    [ 3743.227852] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
    [ 3743.227857] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
    [ 3743.227861] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.1
    [ 3743.227866] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
    [ 3743.227869] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x000006F7 | trm_hw_status0
    [ 3743.227873] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
    [ 3743.227876] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00023FDC | branchlink2
    [ 3743.227879] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0003915A | interruptlink1
    [ 3743.227883] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00004DD2 | interruptlink2
    [ 3743.227886] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
    [ 3743.227889] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
    [ 3743.227893] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x07830000 | data3
    [ 3743.227896] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0E018EA9 | beacon time
    [ 3743.227900] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x310A9156 | tsf low
    [ 3743.227903] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000002 | tsf hi
    [ 3743.227906] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
    [ 3743.227910] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00BCB9F2 | time gp2
    [ 3743.227913] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
    [ 3743.227916] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000022 | uCode version major
    [ 3743.227920] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
    [ 3743.227923] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000230 | hw version
    [ 3743.227926] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
    [ 3743.227930] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0A2E001C | hcmd
    [ 3743.227933] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x82F22002 | isr0
    [ 3743.227937] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00804000 | isr1
    [ 3743.227940] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0800180A | isr2
    [ 3743.227943] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x404128C4 | isr3
    [ 3743.227946] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
    [ 3743.227950] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0064019C | last cmd Id
    [ 3743.227953] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
    [ 3743.227956] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
    [ 3743.227960] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00003C22 | l2p_duration
    [ 3743.227963] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000000F | l2p_mhvalid
    [ 3743.227966] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000084 | l2p_addr_match
    [ 3743.227970] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000000F | lmpm_pmg_sel
    [ 3743.227973] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x30101345 | timestamp
    [ 3743.227977] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00345868 | flow_handler
    [ 3743.228050] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
    [ 3743.228054] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
    [ 3743.228057] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink2
    [ 3743.228060] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
    [ 3743.228064] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
    [ 3743.228067] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data1
    [ 3743.228070] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data2
    [ 3743.228073] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
    [ 3743.228077] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac major
    [ 3743.228080] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
    [ 3743.228083] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | frame pointer
    [ 3743.228086] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | stack pointer
    [ 3743.228089] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
    [ 3743.228093] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
    [ 3743.228100] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you!